# iOS : Unit tests don't see my target identifiers

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing

I have an already existing application that I want to improve by adding some unit tests. 
So I went on the main project settings page, added a new `iOS Unit Testing Bundle`, with the correct target to be tested in the settings panel.

However, when I try to use some classes/methods from this target in these unit tests, I get an error :

> Use of unresolved identifier 'XXXX'

What am I missing?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you made an import '@testable import YourProjectName' in your XCTest file?

Answer (score 0):

- First, you have to build the target succeed
- Second import target files

You must import target files in every file that you want to use classes/methods of this target 
to import it use this

> @testable import TargetName

```
@testable import UnitTestDemo

class ClassNameTest: XCTestCase {

let objectFromTestableTarget = ClassNameFromUnitTestDemo()
.....
}
```

> **Or Checkmark from file inspector**
>
> Checkmark on UnitTest option from file inspector for every file that you want to import

[image: UnitTest option from file inspector]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However when I try to import my project's module, I get an error: `No such module 'ModuleName'`.

Comment: before u use `@testable import TargetName` u must make sure that the target has been built succeeded